# Include binary file with GNU ld linker script

Tags: binary, gnu, ld

I have a working linker script. I want to add another data section whose contents is pulled directly from a file (ld shouldn't parse it and extract the sections and so on). How can I do that?

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386")
ENTRY(start)
SECTIONS
{
  .text 0x100000 : {
    *(.multiboot)
    *(.text)
    *(.code)
    *(.rodata*)
  }
  .data : {
    *(.data)
  }
  .bss : {
    *(.bss)
  }
  kernel_end = .;
  roottask_start = .;
  .data : {

    HERE I WANT TO INCLUDE THE ENTIRE CONTENTS OF ANOTHER (BINARY) FILE

  }
  roottask_end = .;
}
```

Comment: GCC: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864866/c-c-with-gcc-statically-add-resource-files-to-executable-library

Answer (score 24):

You could try using `objcopy` to convert it to a normal object you can link in, and then reference its symbols in the linker script like you would do to a normal object. From the [`objcopy` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objcopy):

> -B *bfdarch*
>
> --binary-architecture=*bfdarch*
>
> Useful when transforming a raw binary input  file  into  an  object
> file.   In this case the output architecture can be set to *bfdarch*.
> This option will be ignored if the input file has a known  *bfdarch*.
> You can access this binary data inside a program by referencing the
> special symbols that are created by the conversion process.   These
> symbols  are  called `_binary_objfile_start`, `_binary_objfile_end` and
> `_binary_objfile_size`.  e.g. you can transform a picture  file  into
> an object file and then access it in your code using these symbols.

...where *objfile* will be expanded to the name of the input object file.

See also the `--rename-section` option.

Comment: The `bfdarch` text is not meant literally (and is not needed).  For confusing see [Linking arbitrary data using gcc arm toolchain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265950/linking-arbitrary-data-using-gcc-arm-toolchain).

Answer (score 19):

You can put raw file to separate section in assembly, and then include this section in linker script.

First you need to create template .S file, eg.

```
.section .rawdata
.incbin "blob1.raw"
```

... and modify linker script to include this section as you like it:

```
.data : {

    *(.rawdata*)

}
```

You can also take a look here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594988/objcopy-prepends-directory-pathname-to-symbol-name/18413411#18413411) for a bit more detailed information about .S template.

Answer (score 8):

Another way with just the linker is to use [TARGET](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Format-Commands.html) and [INPUT](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/File-Commands.html) commands.

```
    TARGET(binary)
    INPUT (./DATA.bin)
    INPUT (./CODE.bin)
    # add more binary files here if needed
    
    OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386")
    
    ENTRY(start)
    
    SECTIONS
    {
        .text 0x100000 : {
            *(.multiboot)
            *(.text)
            *(.code)
            ./CODE.bin
            *(.rodata*)
        }
        .data : {
            *(.data)
        }
        .bss : {
            *(.bss)
        }
        kernel_end = .;
        roottask_start = .;
        .data : {
    
            ./DATA.bin
    
        }
        roottask_end = .;
    }
```

Additionally, you may need alignment stanzas around the binary input.

Comment: This may not work on the ARM architecture. See: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-utils/2001-05/msg00258.html

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is to generate a second linker script containing bytes from your binary using the `BYTE` function, and then include it in the former linker script using the `INCLUDE` directive.

You can generate the script from your binary file using `hexdump` in the following way:

```
cat ramelfs | hexdump -v -e '"BYTE(0x" 1/1 "%02X" ")\n"' > ramelfs.ld
```

And then include it this way :

```
SECTIONS {
    .text : {

        /* ... */

        kramelfs = .;
        INCLUDE "ramelfs.ld" ;
        kramelfs_end = .;

       /* ... */
    }
}
```