# String Concatenation using Precompiler

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, string-concatenation

I have the following problem. I want to include a multi-line textfile as `#define`, i.e. what I need is a constant that stores the value of the text file. Example:

```
File 'f.txt': This\nis\n\nsome\ntext
```

and I want to initialize a constant (at compile time) in the style of

```
#define txtfile "This\\nis\\na\\ntextfile"
```

where the string "This\nis\na\ntextfile" is obtained from concatenating the lines in file f.txt. Is there any way to achieve this using preprocessor commands/macros?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at ["#include" a text file in a C program as a char[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410980/include-a-text-file-in-a-c-program-as-a-char) for a possible alternative which might address your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't directly possible, as the textfile needs processing first. You could write a fairly simple script that performed the appropriate escaping and added the `#define` creating a suitable header file.

Typically you don't actually need the text file as a preprocessor macro expansion, though, you need the file data to appear in the object file and to be accessible as though it where an `extern char[]`.

To do this there are two approaches. The lightweight way is to use an assembler like yasm with an `incbin` directive to produce an object file which has the file data as a labelled section. e.g.:

```
    global f_txt
f_txt:
    incbin "f.txt"
```

Then in the C file you can declare:

```
extern char f_txt[];
```

The more portable way is to use a utility like `xxd -i` to convert the data into an C file with the char array written out 'long hand'.

Comment: objcopy also works for generating an object file: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably going to have to do is have a separate pre-processor program that takes your input file (`f.txt`) and a code section in your special source file (`program.cppx`) like:

```
#superdefine txtfile f.txt
```

The pre-pre-processor you'll have to write yourself but it'll basically replace the `#superdefine` lines with the equivalent `#define` lines based on the file content, producing a file `program.cpp` which you can then feed into the real compiler.

This is quite easy to achieve under UNIXes if you're using a make variant. May not be so easy using an IDE.

Answer (score -1):

One might come up with an idea like the following:

f.txt:

```
This \
is \
some \
text \
```

code.c:

```
#define txtfile "\
#include "f.txt"
"
```

But I don't think this would work. The include line would just be regarded as a String.