# How can I get the contents of a file at build time into my C++ string?

Tags: c++, string, include

I have a file I am compiling in C++ in which I wish to have a string whose value is the contents of a file at the time of compilation.

In other words, I'd like to #include the file but have that be inside double quotes.

How can I do this in C++?

Now what if that file contains double quotes as part of its text, how do I get those escaped?

Comment: You could write a modified Quine ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=quine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correctly create a header with the correct null termination in the string use sed:

```
xxd -i ${INPUT_FILE_NAME} | sed s/}\;/,0x00}\;/ > ${INPUT_FILE_PATH}.h
```

See http://gamesfromwithin.com/quick-tip-working-with-shaders-on-ios for details.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `xxd -i /tmp/your_file > /tmp/your_file_as_string.c`

Which will define a string literal for you:

```
$ cat /tmp/your_file_as_string.c
unsigned char _tmp_inc[] = {
  0x2e, 0x2f, 0x42, 0x61, 0x74, 0x63, 0x68, 0x2f, 0x6e, 0x65, 0x78, 0x74,
  0x4f, 0x6f, 0x6c, 0x73, 0x2f, 0x73, 0x63, 0x68, 0x65, 0x6d, 0x61, 0x5f,
  ...
  0x74, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x64, 0x61, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x2e, 0x65, 0x63,
  0x0a
};
unsigned int _tmp_inc_len = 1513;
```

Now you can use that defined string.

Comment: Doesn't give a terminating 0x0, is there a way to get xxd to add the null at the end of the string?

Comment: @WilliamKF: not directly, unfortunately.  This answer on SO gives an approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410980/include-a-text-file-in-a-c-program-as-a-char

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of is to have another file generated off your file as a pre-compile step. You can build a small utility which will do it for you. This utility can take care of double-quotes and you can call it before compilation in your build file

Answer (score 1):

An obvious (if somewhat naive) way is to make a system call and invoke `cpp -x c++ file.cpp`, and then read the contents of the stream directly into a string just like you would any other file-read operation.

This invokes the C preprocessor on `file.cpp` in C++ mode, which is exactly identical to running `#include ...` on it. This value will then be stored in the `string` object.

Answer (score 1):

Try to see if your compiler/linker suite has a program called something like `bin2obj`.  If it exists, it will usually take any file and generate a `.o` or `.obj` file that you can instruct the linker to link into your program.  (How to do this varies by build environment.)

Typically, then, you'll end up with one or two symbols you can make visible to your code like so:

```
extern "C" const char * myFile_start;
extern "C" unsigned int myFile_size;
```

The linker will make sure `myFile_start` points at the start of your file, and `myFile_size` gives you an indication of the length.

The symbol names may vary, though: you can use the `objdump` or `nm` or `dumpbin` utilities (again, depending on compiler/linker suite) to investigate the generated `.o` or `.obj` to find the symbol names (if they're not already documented in your `obj2bin` tool documentation).

Please note that this bloats your executable (usually the `.data` or `.rodata` sections or equivalent), which can be a problem on some platforms.

(If you don't have a bin2obj, you may be able to find one by hunting around on a search engine for "bin2obj" with your compiler/IDE name.)