# Is it possible to store the contents of pnames.icu in a Windows C++ global variable?

Tags: c++, winapi

We are contemplating changing from PCRE regular expressions to
ICU regular expressions to take advantage of ICU's UTF-8 Unicode regular
expressions. We have wriiten a test program to load the ICU pnames.icu file
which is necessary to compile and exercise the ICU UTF-8 Regular
expressions which appears to be functioning correctly.
            Is it possible to store the contents of pnames.icu in a Windows
DLL global variable in order to avoid shipping the ICU pnames.icu to users?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes. One way is to stuff them in the app's resources and use find/load resource to load them

Comment: @Captain Oblivious, Which WinAPI functions should we use to read the contents of pnames.icu and stuff them in the app's resources? Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Hi Captain && All, We googled and found this Stack Overflow article. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933295/embed-text-file-in-a-resource-in-a-native-windows-application------Embed Text File in a Resource in a native Windows Application. Would it be applicable to pnames.icu? Thank you

Comment: Yes. The information in that post definitely applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start by adding the files to the resource script in the same way you do an icon. The difference is you will specify the resource by name instead of an integer value and tell the resource compiler that the files are a custom resource type called "ICU"

```
pname1      ICU     "pname1.icu"
pname2      ICU     "pname2.icu"
pname3      ICU     "pname3.icu"
```

To load the resource you will first need to find it by name and by the type (in this case ICU). Once you have found it you can tell windows to load the resource data and then "lock" it to obtain a pointer to it.

```
//  Find the resource
HRSRC hRes = FindResource(NULL, L"pname1", L"ICU");

//  Load the resource 
HGLOBAL hResLoad = LoadResource(NULL, hRes);

void* icuData = LockResource(hResLoad);

// ... do something with the resource @ icuData


//  We're done so let it go.
UnlockResource(icuData);
```

Comment: CAPTAIN Oblivious, I just accepted your Stack Overflow answer. If we do the same thing on Solaris UNIX, how might we proceed? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Frank Not sure what to recommend for Solaris. It's not likely to be a built in feature though. You might want to look at a simple resource packager.

Comment: CAPTAIN Oblivious, We googled some more and found this Stack Overflow article about how to embed a file in gcc executable library. However, it says nothing about Solarix UNIX. Thank you for your help.                                             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864866/c-c-with-gcc-statically-add-resource-files-to-executable-library

Comment: @Frank: GCC is a compiler; Oracle Solaris UNIX is an operating system. The two are not at odds; GCC can compile Solaris executables.

Comment: @MSalters, Thank you for your advice on Oracle Solaris. On Windows XP Professional , we are getting a  NULL pointer from HRSRC hRes = FindResource(NULL, L"pname1", L"ICU"). In addition, when we call GetModuleHandle(DLLFullyQualifiedPath) we get GetErrorCodes 126 or 2. Have you encoutered this problem before. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: Use a tool like [Resource Hacker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Hacker) to check if the `pname1` reosurce was succesfully added. Note that `FindResource(NULL` checks the .EXE; you need a valid handle from `GetModuleHandle(DLLPath)` to load a resource from a DLL.

Comment: @Msalters, We fixed the pname1 resource problem by following your advice. However. when we call HMODULE handle = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\mdRightFielder.dll"));, we GetLastError() of 126 still. We  were wondering if our pathname argument is correctly formatted. THank you for your advice.

Comment: @Frank: The path looks like a bad choice, but well-formatted. Have you checked the actual directory? (* _It's a bad choice because your DLL is not a Microsoft DLL shipped as part of Windows; use_ \Program Files\ _instead._ *)

Comment: @MSalters, Thank you for your help on the the path issue,

Comment: CAPTAIN Oblivious, I just applied your code to read and store the contents of ICU UNICODE regex pnames.icu in a global variable. Thank you.