# Including Text Files in Build of Visual Studio 2013 Solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I want a text file to be included in the build, so I used `Add->Existing Item` to load it into the solution. However, I can't open it in a ifstream unless I use an absolute path to the original file. I set `Excluded from Build` to `No` and Item Type to `Text`. For a relative path to `file.txt`, I tried `"file.txt"`, `"../file.txt"`, `"/file.txt"` but none of them work. I don't know if it's my syntax that's wrong, or if it's just not included in the build, or both.

The program is in C++.

I came across some old answers that mentioned an option to specify additional directories in the build, but I don't see it in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Confused.  Why are you trying to compile a text file?   Just what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a function that loads a user-specified text file through a filestream. I'd like to execute that function on a private "default" text file at runtime.

Comment: So you want to be able to read the file, but, not allow it to be seen by the user?  What do you mean by "user-specified"?  Will the file change often?

Comment: Yes to the first question. That is precisely the goal. Perhaps I'm not going about it correctly. I mean it calls a openFileDialog, so the user can specify their own text file. It will vary from user to user.

Comment: If they can specify their own text file, how can you expect to protect the file from viewing?  I have a solution if you have one specific file you want to protect, but, not for this scenario.

Comment: I'll try to clarify: I want my _input_ text file to be kept private, not the _output_ from passing it to the function. It just happens to be used in the same function that allows the user to use their own text file. (The function parses a large quantity of data.)

Comment: Got it.  Have you looked into creating a custom resource template from the text file?  Effectively, you can bind the file to the executable, extract it at run time, read it, and remove it when done.

Comment: You mean like resx or restext? I'm not familiar with how to read them. Is there an analogy to getline where you can specify a delimiter? Could you explain briefly/point me toward a reference? Thanks.

Comment: Per request in comment section, this has been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933295/embed-text-file-in-a-resource-in-a-native-windows-application)