# How to embed a XML file into EXE with VS2013 (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I want to embed a XML file into EXE with VS2013 (i.e. I don't want to ship the XML to my customer, only the EXE).

I'm using C++ (MFC), and I tried to put it into `.rc` file. But it gives back only something like `IDR_XML1` and in `Resource.h`, there's `#define IDR_XML1 108`

Then how should I load this XML file in my code?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [this][1] solution (embedding a TEXTFILE in a resource)?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933295/embed-text-file-in-a-resource-in-a-native-windows-application

Comment: Have you considering simply pasting the XML into a string resource?