# Reading a static file in C++ within the code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a code which will read the xml file using pugi xml. Given below is the content of the same.

```
xml_document doc;
xml_parse_result result = doc.load_file(sXMLFilePath.c_str());
```

Here sXMLFilePath is the file present in my system. I want to hard-code this file into the code itself. I dont want to read this file from the machine. Meaning I want to make this file static.

Also if the file size is more than 30MB, can I compress the same?

Comment: Not directly. You can `#include` files, but not inside the string literals. The easiest way would be to use a tool such as XD that takes that file and spits it it out as a C++ array, then add that to the build.

Comment: My reason for doing this is, I dont want to expose the user on which file I am referring to. Just want to hard-code one file and give the result. The file size is around 25mb.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz how do I use that XD tool? Should it be there on the machine where I the application will be actually used. I simply dont want to expose the file to anyone. I want to keep that file within my application only.

Comment: Basically you run this on your file before the build, and then you can e.g. `#include` the generated C file. It doesn't have to be on the destination machine, as it job ends before your build starts.

Comment: Can you pass me the link where I can find the XD tool?

Comment: https://www.fourmilab.ch/xd/

Comment: The XML file has 660000 rows. Its not able to fit in within a c *. Any other option? I just dont want to expose the file to end user.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be able to fit?

Comment: There is a limitation for a char array right? Can you provide me a sample code to perform the same?

Comment: What limitation? Did you actually try that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933295/embed-text-file-in-a-resource-in-a-native-windows-application has solved my query

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176111/how-to-dump-a-binary-file-as-a-c-c-string-literal