# Reading a user-defined text resource file line by line

Tags: c++, resources, scanf

I need to read the contents of a text file and store the values to variables. Consider this simple file:

```
2
-0.5    -0.5     0.0
 0.5    -0.5     0.0
```

When specifying its filename (so without using resources), I proceed like this with `fscanf_s`:

```
FILE *pFile;
fopen_s(&pFile, filename.c_str(), "r");

fscanf_s(pFile, "%d", &nPoints);
points = new Vec3[nPoints];

for (int n = 0; n < nPoints; ++n)
    fscanf_s(pFile, "%lf %lf %lf", &points[n][0], &points[n][1], &points[n][2]);

fclose(pFile);
```

and the data is saved to two vectors, each having three values.

Now, I would like to do the same but with a file that is included as a user-defined resource. First, I follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933357/6080325) to load the data into a buffer. The problem is that I don't know what to do with this buffer to retreive the data and save it in a similar way. I have tried using the `sscanf_s` function:

```
sscanf_s(buffer, "%d", &nPoints);
points = new Vec3[nPoints];

for (int n = 0; n < nPoints; ++n) {
    sscanf_s(buffer, "%lf %lf %lf", &points[n][0], &points[n][1], &points[n][2]);
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work like I expected. The number of points is read correctly into the `nPoints` variable, but both vectors end up with the values 2, -0.5, -0.5.

How can I save the values from the buffer to my `Vec3`s? Or is there a simpler alternative that I should consider?

Comment: Are you really  sure programming with c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `sscanf_s()` you are passing it the same `buffer` pointer each time, so it keeps re-reading from the same `2` value over and over.

You need to advance the pointer after each read.  The return value of `sscanf_f()` is the number of *fields read*, but you would need the number of *characters consumed* instead, which you can get with the `%n` format specifier, eg:

```
char *ptr = buffer;
int consumed;

sscanf_s(ptr, "%d%n", &nPoints, &consumed);
ptr += consumed;

points = new Vec3[nPoints];

for (int n = 0; n < nPoints; ++n) {
    sscanf_s(ptr, "%lf %lf %lf%n", &points[n][0], &points[n][1], &points[n][2], &consumed);
    ptr += consumed;
}
```

A better option is to use C++ style I/O instead of C style I/O.  For instance, you can assign the `buffer` data to a [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and then read from that <sup>1</sup>, eg:

```
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream iss(buffer);

iss >> nPoints;
points = new Vec3[nPoints];

for (int n = 0; n < nPoints; ++n) {
    iss >> points[n][0] >> points[n][1] >> points[n][2];
}
```

<sup>1: to read from a file instead, simply replace `std::istringstream` with [`std::ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream).</sup>

Or, if you want to avoid the overhead of allocating a `std::string` copy of the `buffer` data, you can [write a custom `std::basic_streambuf` class](http://www.voidcn.com/article/p-vjnlygmc-gy.html) (or find a 3rd party implementation) that can read from your `buffer` (or even better, from the original resource directly), eg:

```
#include <iostream>

SomeCharArrayStreamBuf buf(buffer, size);
std::istream is(&buf);

is >> nPoints;
points = new Vec3[nPoints];

for (int n = 0; n < nPoints; ++n) {
    is >> points[n][0] >> points[n][1] >> points[n][2];
}
```

---

Once you switch to using C++ I/O streams, you can greatly simplify things even further by utilizing containers and algorithms from C++'s standard library, eg:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<Vec3> points; // <-- instead of 'Vec3 *pointers;'
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, Vec3 &v)
{
    in >> v[0] >> v[1] >> v[2];
    return in;
}

strm >> nPoints; // <-- where strm is your chosen istream class object
points.reserve(nPoints); // <-- instead of 'new Vec3[nPoints];'

std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator(strm), nPoints, std::back_inserter(points)); // <-- instead of a manual reading loop
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I like using the C style I/O because it is closer to the syntax in Matlab and Python, which I use more frequently. What makes the C++ commands better in this case? Would they work the same if the values in the file were comma-separated?

Comment: For comma-separated data, look at [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), which has an optional `delim` parameter that you can set to `','`.