# win32/C++ Embed a Text File in a Resource

Tags: c++, winapi, resources

I try to embebed a custom TXT file in a win32 exe file, using codeblocks (TDM-GCC compiler) in win10 x64 machine.

Using the method answered by [***In silico***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933295/embed-text-file-in-a-resource-in-a-native-windows-application), in similar question "buffer" variable only shows the first 3 bytes.
Ex: Data.txt file contains: "HOLA MUNDO" (22 bytes checked in hex editor)

But when I show 'char* buffer' variable using MessageBox(), it only shows first three bytes of DATA.txt: **ÿþH**

Here is my code:

```
void LoadFileResource() {

char* data = NULL;
DWORD  rcSize = 0;

TCHAR  sResName[5]  = _T("#107"); // ID from resource.h file for DATA.txt
TCHAR  sRestype[8] = _T("DATAREG"); // custom typeID from .rc file for DATA.txt

HRSRC rc = ::FindResource(NULL, sResName, sRestype);

HGLOBAL rcData = ::LoadResource(NULL, rc);
rcSize = ::SizeofResource(NULL, rc); // Have value of 22, and DATA.txt have 22 bytes    
data = static_cast<const char*>(::LockResource(rcData));

char* buffer = new char[rcSize+1];
::memcpy(buffer, data, rcSize);
buffer[rcSize+1] = 0; // NULL terminator, I think here is 0 for very LAST position of buffer

MessageBox(NULL, buffer, NULL, MB_OK); // Only show 3 first bytes from DATA.txt

delete[] buffer;
}
```

Also checked the resources compiled in final EXE file and content of DATA.txt is there "HOLA MUNDO".

What is the right way to manipulate/show content of data/buffer??

***Updating:***
Even using another conversion mode for data, discarding 'new char[]' and 'memcpy()':

```
data = (char*)(::LockResource(rcData));

LPBYTE sData = (LPBYTE)data;
LPTSTR sXml = (LPTSTR)sData;

DWORD  buffSize = strlen(sXml); // Result in 3, don't know why.
MessageBox(NULL, sXml, NULL, MB_OK); //Shows again only first 3 bytes of DATA.txt
```

Same result **ÿþH**.

Comment: Try `MessageBoxA`.

Comment: `new char[rcSize+1]` creates an array with valid indexes of 0 through `rcSize`. Then `buffer[rcSize+1] = 0;` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of access out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Even with MessageBoxA, or using another conversion for manipulate data, show again only firs 3 bytes of DATA.txt . Updating question in main post.

Comment: It seems content of DATA.txt is not suitable to display. Write some ASCII string to DATA.txt if you use `MessageBoxA`. Or show HEX value of your DATA.txt content so I can do a further investigation.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT , your right. Apparently my original DATA.txt is UTF with BOM encoded, as I says in main post the first bytes of TXT are **ÿþ** typically for BOM files; My code can show only ANSI/UTF encoded data, I don't know if is something regarded with settings of compiler or just the functions I use. But converting DATA.txt to ANSI or UTF (without BOM) all code works as expected. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: @Lokotito You can post an answer to make this question and solution clear. It will be helpful for others who will see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all for your comments and responses.

I was playing a lite more with my code and also searching some info about the error.
Apparently the first 2 bytes in my DATA.txt file (**ÿþ**) indicates that is a **UTF-16 (big endian)** encoding type, opening in note++ I can see is a **UCS-2 LE BOM** encoding type.
Finally changing the DATA.txt file to **UTF-8** encoding  (without BOM) let me assign the content of this resource to a variable and play with it in my code.