# Can you get the compiler's command-line contents from within the compiled program?

Tags: c++, command-line, compiler-options

For silly reasons, I am required to have a string with the options the compiler executable got embedded in the program I'm compiling. This can be achieved by the build system or build-system-generator, albeit in an ugly way; but I was wondering if I can get my *compiler* to give me that information.

Language: C++

Compiler: Each of g++, clang++, icpc, MSVC

What I tried: I dumped all of the defines with `$CXX -dM -E -x c++ - < /dev/null`, and didn't see something relevant, for the first 3 compilers.

Note: Obviously the language itself does not provide for this to happen, I'm asking about compiler-specific features.

Comment: Some specific details are available as macros. Are you after some specific option?  You'll find that many flags have a corresponding macro associated with them, but you get each one individually. (_à la carte_ so to speak.) e.g.: [standard macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#Predefined_macros), or macros specific to [MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-170) or [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html)

Comment: @Wyck: No, I want the full string . Or rather, I don't want it at all, but somebody else thinks they want it.

Answer (score 2):

This is completely out of the scope of the C++ standard. Unless your compiler provides an explicit means of doing so, it is up to you to implement it yourself. And the chances of all major C++ compilers implementing this in an identical way, or at least in some way that can be determined, on individual compiler-by-compiler basis (with a nested hairball of `#ifdef`s), are slim to none.

Therefore it is up to you to implement this yourself. You will need to take whatever build framework you are using to compile and link your C++ code -- be it a makefile, a script, or whatever tool gets used for it -- and make the appropriate changes to capture all options that get passed to the compiler, and provide them to your applications.

In an automake-processed `Makefile.am`, for example, I would do something like this:

```
BUILT_SOURCES += compilation_options.H

compilation_options.H:
    echo "#define compilation_options \"$(CXXFLAGS)\"" >compilation_options.H
```

That should be good enough unless `CXXFLAGS` has some quotes or specific punctuation, in which case this will require a little bit more work. Perhaps toss in `$(CPPFLAGS)` and `$(LDFLAGS)`, for a good measure.

You will need to figure out how to implement something similar for whatever build framework you're using; there is no universal button, somewhere, that can be pushed to have this done automatically with every compiler. This needs to be implemented explicitly.

Comment: That's useful if I were using autotools, but it doesn't answer my literal question. I can get by without compiler support, I would just rather avoid the hassle if possible.

Comment: I believe I answered that, in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's too bold to say that the answer to your question is **no**, in that you cannot get the command line arguments that were used to compile some *arbitrary* application. So I'm going to assume this is a program that you're building yourself.

Furthermore, **no**, there's no way to see the *command line* itself as a preprocessor macro.

#### Adding metadata to your executable

You can arrange for your build system to embed the build commands into your executable.

Firstly, you will want some mechanism for producing the embedded information itself.  Here's one way:

```
make clean
make -n >buildinfo
```

Then, to embed the buildinfo in a text section of your ELF executable:

```
objcopy --add-section .build_info=buildinfo path_to_your_executable
```

You can extract this info again with:

```
readelf -p .build_info path_to_your_executable
```

or

```
objdump -s --section .build_info path_to_your_executable
```

**For Windows**

For Windows executables (PE files), you'll want to embed your build info as a custom [resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/how-to-include-resources-at-compile-time?view=msvc-170), and you'll need your own custom way to extract it.  The procedure is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933357/1563833).

#### Alternate route

If you want the build info available to the program itself, you can use `xxd`.

For example:

```
xxd -i buildinfo >buildinfo.c
```

Fictional contents of *buildinfo* for illustration purposes:

```
Hello, world!
```

Resulting contents of *buildinfo.c*:

```
unsigned char buildinfo[] = {
  0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x2c, 0x20, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64,
  0x21, 0x0a
};
unsigned int buildinfo_len = 14;
```

Just compile and link this file along with others in your program.  Then you could manually write your command-line processing handling to include a flag like `--show-build-info` that would output this string to stdout at run-time or put it in your *about box* or whatever is appropriate for your particular application.