# How to insert a folder that contains files txt in vs c++?

Tags: c++

I wrote code c++ in visual studio, this code uses data contained in text files (the number of files exceeds 100) and I want to use the executable file on other computers. The problem is that these files cannot be opened. Is there a solution to include these files with the code?

I have tried to add the files to the project but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: On Windows, I would recommend to embed the data as **resources** inside the `.exe` file. Some Win32 API function can then access the data like memory. This can only be used for *read-only data* however.

Comment: Create an installer, which installs the files in a well-known location?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2933295