# #include an image in ansi C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, image-file

I am writing a program that creates an image file. I want the "original" image to be hard-coded in the program's binary.

I was thinking...

```
char image[] = {
#include"image.jpg"
}
```

But I need to somehow convert the image into a format that can be #included into a c file as a char array?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["#include" a text file in a C program as a char\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410980/include-a-text-file-in-a-c-program-as-a-char)

Comment: yes, you want xxd, careful about size, you'll eat stack here.

Comment: @IanNorton: not, unless you are crazy enough to use it as a local variable..

Comment: @IanNorton xxd works, post as an answer and i'll accept it :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, use the unix tool [**xxd**](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xxd/) to create a c char array import of a given binary file, Like so:

```
$ xxd -i imgfile.dat > imgfile.h
```

This should produce output like:

```
unsigned char imgfile[] = {
  0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x20, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x0a
};
unsigned int imgfile_len = 12;
```

See also: ["#include" a text file in a C program as a char[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410980/include-a-text-file-in-a-c-program-as-a-char)

Answer (score 2):

You could write a little program that takes a jpg file as input and outputs a C initializer. Then #include that file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ch;
    int count = 0;
    printf("static const char array[] = {\n");
    while ((ch = getchar()) != -1) {
       printf("0x%02X, ", ch);
       ++count;
       if ((count % 16) == 0)
           printf("\n");
   }
   printf("\n};\n#define ARRAY_SIZE %d\n", count);
}
```

Compile the file (call it initialzer.c or something) and do:

```
./initializer <pic.jpg >jpeg.h
```

You could get fancy and make the array name configurable if you want.

Comment: indeed, but how do I convert a jpeg into { 'a', 'b', 'c' } ??

Comment: Just a quick and dirty addition:

`printf("static const char %s[] = {\n", (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "array");` — but better to stop going too far :-) argc == 2 might be another alternative.

Comment: It is too easy to get sucked in. :-)

Comment: Quite true! By the way, markdown ate your pipes. I took the liberty to edit it

Comment: You don't really need `#define ARRAY_SIZE` at the end. This is actually an array, you can use `sizeof`.

Comment: @ChrisLutz True, but I had that count lying around and it seemed a shame to waste it.

Comment: You _could_ always write the array to a .c file, then write a declaration of the array (with the size) to a separate .h file. Though most compilers will optimize what you have to the same thing anyway. (Also, no include guards?)

Comment: Hey, it was an on-the-fly example. I really should have been doing serious work anyway. Stack Overflow makes the mind wander. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

- Open the image file in **binary read mode**
- Determine the **size** of the file
- **Allocate memory** to store it
- Read the file into memory using `fread`

Write the whole thing in a `.h` file and `# include` that file in your code.

Comment: +1. Yes, that is easier than to download an editor. But if he is in Linux, He needn't :-)