# Hardcoding large data set into executable?

Tags: c++

I'd like to hardcode large sets of data (integer arrays of varying length, a library of text strings, etc) directly into an executable file, so there are no additional files.

My question is, what is the most practical and organized method for doing this in C++?  Where would I place the data, in terms of header or source files?  What structure should I use?

I realize this isn't the accepted way of dealing with data.  But humour me!

Comment: Have seen this on SO before...  looking.

Comment: try putting it in a different .cpp file, for example, `resources.cpp`, then make it `extern` and give it a header file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410980/include-a-text-file-in-a-c-program-as-a-char related, not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What is your target OS? If it's Windows you can use [raw resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa381039(v=vs.85).aspx) linked into your project. You can access them as usual ([example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194809.aspx)).

Comment: @stan - I'm compiling on windows, but I'd need to switch compilers at some point to make mac/debian binaries I'm afraid

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/resources.html), it's a good example of doing this in a portable and organized way. In short, it converts files to char arrays that get built into the binary and uses static initializers to set up a central registry of files that have been compiled in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For both C++ and C, you may use header file to put declarations for these variables, and then place actual initialization code into .c (or .cc) file. Both C and C++ have decent initializers syntax. For example:

mydata.h:

```
extern int x;
extern int a[10];
extern unsigned char *s;
```

mydata.c:

```
#include "mydata.h"
int x = 123;
int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
unsigned char *s = "mystring";
```

then main.c will have:

```
#include "mydata.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(const int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("%d, %d, %s\n", x,a[5],s);
}
```

test run looks like this:

```
$gcc -o main main.c mydata.c
$ ./main 
123, 6, mystring
```

Now, to really get organized, one would write Perl/Python/PHP script to generate such formed files from your datasources, like SQL database of CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/bin2obj/

Convert your data to an OBJ and link into your project.