# How to store C++ source code inside an executable?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have 3 C++ files that I would like to generate using an executable file, I mean if I click on the executable my 3 files should appear beside it.

So I thought about using `ofstream` and then create my three files like this. But the problem is, my 3 files contain a lot of lines and escaping the `"` and `'` will take a lot of time...

How can I embed C++ source code inside my executable without the hassle of escaping the string literals?

Comment: Use [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Comment: But how ? do you have a tutorial ? Thank you

Comment: And with string literals is not a good idea because in my code I have a lot of " and if I use the strings I will have a lot of problems for instance if in my code I have `std::string a = "std::cout << "Hello"<<std::endl;"` I would have not `std::cout << "Hello"<<std::endl;`

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638557/read-a-file-into-a-string-at-compile-time.

Comment: @VickyHarris `std::string a = "std::cout << "Hello"<<std::endl;"` is **not** using raw string literals. Did you read the link?

Comment: Resource-files or `objcopy` on Linux should do the trick. But there really isn't much you could do in a system-independent way apart from embedding the text in the source-file of your program.

Comment: @VickyHarris: a [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) would look more like this: `std::string a = R"mycode(std::cout << "Hello"<<std::endl;)mycode";` Everything between `mycode(` and `)mycode` is stored as-is in the string (`std::cout << "Hello"<<std::endl;`) and thus doesn't need to be escaped in the literal. This is fine for a short number of lines, but if you have a LOT of lines to store, you are better off saving the lines to files that are embedded into your exe at link-time. Then your code can simply extract that data to file at run-time.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Linux or similar, you can use `objcopy` to do this easily during your build process:

```
objcopy --input binary --output elf64-x86-64 myfile.cpp myfiletxt.o
```

What this does is to create an object file called myfiletxt.o which you can then link into your executable.  This object file will contain a symbol which is the entire content of `myfile.cpp`.  You can then print it out etc.

Comment: What's the name of the symbol? Can it be changed?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235175/how-do-i-add-contents-of-text-file-as-a-section-in-an-elf-file

Comment: @Quentin: in this example the symbols are `_binary_myfile_cpp_{start,end,size}`.  I think you can change them using `objcopy --redefine-sym ...`.