# Hint on how to include an html text in a C++ source file

Tags: html, c++, c++11

I have an html source file which I use to edit and test with an html editor. For my purposes I would like to include this file in my C++11 source code by instantiating a `std::string` containing the html file content as it is.

For now, I am using the following way, which is not ideal as it require an unwanted modification to the html source code, as shown below:

```
std::string my_html = 
#include "my.html"
;
```

where `my.html` contains something like:

```
R"(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</html>
)"
```

Note the `R"(` and `)"` tokens. They are there for the only purpose of allowing the C+11 `std::string` to be instantiated by the compiler.

Of course, those tokens make my html source code non-html compliant. I'd like to have them removed from the html source, yet be able to instantiate the string in some other way.

Do you know any solution? I prefer standard solutions to pre-processor tricks. However, a pre-processor help is okay in the only case the are no standard solutions.

Comment: That's somewhat crazy. Why not just read the file off disk dynamically when the program is running?

Comment: @meagar, not crazy at all, why should i need to load it from a disk dynamically?

Comment: The only problem with your resulting string is the initial newline. Put the DOCTYPE on the same line as the R.

Comment: Have your make/buikd system takr raw html, and output a .cpphtml wrapped in `R"`$guid`(` and `)`$guid`"`.

Comment: @tux3: do you know c++11? it compiles as it should

Comment: @Martin Yes, I'm an idiot. I deleted that comment 5s after posting it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410980/include-a-text-file-in-a-c-program-as-a-char)

Comment: @Bert that's a totally different question

Comment: @Martin: is it okay if I close this question, or do you have additional concerns (apart from the invalid claim about the HTML)?

Comment: @Alf wait.. I am considering your answer, but I don't get it. Why should the HTML be valid when putting DOCTYPE on the same line as the R?

Comment: @Martin: sorry, i haven't drunk enough coffee. one needs to also use a macro for generating the `R`, I think. checking...

Comment: @alf , yes, probably a pre-processor trick (not standard macro) is the only possible way. I am using g++, for anyone who is willing to give a solution

Comment: After checking, no I can't see any way to make the C++ compiler (even a specific one such as g++) do this on its own. Some manual or automated preprocessing is needed. Instead of the Unix-land specific translation recommended in the suggested duplicate, I think I would just let the build generate a file with the `char const s[] = R"(` followed by contents of HTML file followed by `")`. Easy to do both in Windows and Unix-land.