# boost function to create C++ 11 raw string

Tags: c++, boost

In C++ 11, you can create a raw string like this

```
string rawString = R"delim(STRING_WITH_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS)delim";
```

It will ignore all the special characters. However, this feature is not implemented in GCC 4.4 or older.  Is there a boost equivalent for this feature? If not, what is the best way to create a raw string in an older version of C++ implementation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Raw String literals is a core language feature that cannot be implemented in any library. Basically, because the C++ standard specifies how string literal should be parsed. There may be compiler specific extensions though. But, there is no portable way to do Raw strings pre - C++11.

Even in C++11 and beyond that we have Raw string literals, its a Core language feature whose syntax and semantics [is dictated](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.literal#lex.string) by the standard. In brief, its a compile time feature. Your question can be also likened to something like replicating C++14 `constexpr` features using normal C++03.

> what is the best way to create a raw string in an older version of C++ implementation?

See [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410980/include-a-text-file-in-a-c-program-as-a-char), it may be helpful