# Include a file as a string

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Is there a preprocessor trick that allows me to "include" a file as a string in a header?

Something like this:

**`a.txt`**

```
lorem ipsum dolorem
sit amet
```

and the "magic" include call similar to this:

**`header.h`**

```
MAGICINCLUDE(a.txt, atxt)
```

As a result, the preprocessor does tricks and the above line is equivalent to this:

```
const char* atxt = "lorem ipsum dolorem\n\
sit amet";
```

No external tool shall be used, just the preprocessor: I am trying to get rid of my python scripts that do this.

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/25021520/3512538

Comment: No, it can't be done solely with the preprocessor.   It would not be difficult to write a simple C or C++ program that reads the text file, and outputs a header containing the required string with suitable formatting.

Comment: Also may be of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864866/c-c-with-gcc-statically-add-resource-files-to-executable-library

Comment: static const std::string vertex_shader_text {
#include "glmain.vert"
};

Comment: R"(
#version 110
)"

Answer (score 2):

**No, there isn't.**

You will need external tools:

- ["#include" a text file in a C program as a char[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410980/include-a-text-file-in-a-c-program-as-a-char)
- [C/C++ with GCC: Statically add resource files to executable/library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864866/c-c-with-gcc-statically-add-resource-files-to-executable-library)