# Get content of a header file hardcoded into a program as text

Tags: c++

I need to have a content of one of header files at compile time. Is it possible using, for example, `#define` or `constexpr` under `Visual Studio 2015`?

P.S> To clarify, why I need that:
I have some config files which looks like this:

```xml
<ModelSettingsData version="1.0" xmlns="ded" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
    <Param name="lightOuterLanding[0]"  bus="L_ESS_DC"              load="200"/>
    <Param name="lightOuterLanding[1]"  bus="R_ESS_DC"              load="200"/>
    <Param name="lightOuterLanding[2]"  bus="TOWING_DC or APU_DC"   load="8"/>
    <Param name="lightOuterTaxi[0]"     bus="L_AC"                  load="92"/>
    <Param name="lightOuterTaxi[1]"     bus="R_AC"                  load="92"/>
    <Param name="lightOuterRwyOff[0]"   bus="L_AC"                  load="65"/>
    <Param name="lightOuterRwyOff[1]"   bus="R_AC"                  load="65"/>
</ModelSettingsData>
```

and the header file like this:

```cpp
struct ElecLightPower {
    float lightOuterLanding[4];
    float lightOuterTaxi[2];
    float lightOuterRwyOff[2];
    // ...
};
```

I need to fill the structure from the header file with the data which is calculated using parameters from the config file. Now I read this header as text on the program init and do what I need (actually just count byte shifts for every parameter), but the problem comes when I update the header in source code, but forget to put updated version of that file in the folder with the binary. For that reason I just want somehow to get the content of `.h` file in my code, to not read it from the disk on runtime.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by `have a content of one of header files at compile time`.  Isn't the header file present on your hard drive, and therefore available at compile time?

Comment: What do you think normally happens when you `#include` a header file?

Comment: **What are you really trying to do?**

Comment: It might be possible, but since you haven't really said what 'it' is it's not possible to say any more.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Updated the header and put additional information in the question body

Comment: @selbie added `P.S>` part to question

Comment: You need to implement a code generation step before build that will read config and generate C++ source file with data.

Comment: Do you actually want to [include a file as a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256465/include-a-file-as-a-string)?

Comment: @JakobStark yes, I read these questions, but there is no solution for my case: Windows + file which can be compiled