# Pipe hex into sed and append its output to a file

Tags: bash, sed, hex, pipe, ascii

I'm trying to write a script which gets the hex characters of an object file and then redirects the output (in ascii) to a specific line in a file.

Basically, i do

```
export FILE=myobj_file
export j=''
for b in $(objdump -d -M intel $FILE | grep "^ " | cut -f2); do j+='\x'$b; done; echo $j
```

This prints me out the hex code (shellcode):

```
\xeb\x0d\x5e\x31\xc9\x67\x2a\x42\x4b\x55\x55\x55\x85\xc8\xc3\xc4\x85\xd9\xc2\xeb\xe8\xe8\xe8\xe8\xe9\xe9\xe9\xe9
```

and i want to write that to a file containing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() { 
unsigned char code[] = {{PLACEHOLDER}} /*Here need to be inserted*/
printf("Length:  %d\n", strlen(code));

    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;
    ret();
    return 0;


}
```

I tried piping that output to sed as:

```
sed '6s/%d/$j/' file.c
```

but i get an error.

My result should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() { 
unsigned char code[] = \
"\xeb\x0d\x5e\x31\xc9\x67\x2a\x42\x4b\x55\x55\x55\x85\xc8\xc3\xc4\x85\xd9\xc2\xeb\xe8\xe8\xe8\xe8\xe9\xe9\xe9\xe9";
printf("Length:  %d\n", strlen(code));

    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;
    ret();
    return 0;


}
```

And either i get an error with sed or i get sed to insert HEX code instead of ASCII, by converting \x41 to 'A', instead of inserting \x41.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the answer of [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54333287/8344060), we make use of a template file with a placeholder (identical copy here):

```
/* ... */

int main() { 
    unsigned char code[] = "{{PLACEHOLDER}}"
    printf("Length:  %d\n", strlen(code));
    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;
    ret();
    return 0;
}

/* ... */
```

So now we can replace the `{{PLACEHOLDER}}` as:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}
      (NR==FNR) && /^ /{
         sub(" +$","",$2);gsub(" ","\\x",$2); string=string "\\x" $2
         next;
      }
      (NR == FNR) { next }
      /{{PLACEHOLDER}}/{ sub("{{PLACEHOLDER}}",string ) }
      1' <(objdump -d -M intel $FILE) code.c > updated_output.c
```

Comment: Good answer! With this awk-only solution you avoid the sed _argument list too long error_. And it would be simple to change it to write compilable c code.

Comment: There was a small fix needed (@lewicz)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a placeholder in the c file:

```
/* ... */

int main() { 
    unsigned char code[] = "{{PLACEHOLDER}}"
    printf("Length:  %d\n", strlen(code));
    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;
    ret();
    return 0;
}

/* ... */
```

Then use a 2 step approach (using /bin/ls as example):

```
string="$(objdump -d -M intel /bin/ls | awk -F'\t' '/^ /{gsub(/^|\y \y/, "\\\\x", $2);gsub(/ /,"",$2);printf "%s", $2}')"
sed "s/{{PLACEHOLDER}}/${string}/" file.c
```

Comment: @kvantour I see what you mean. But that doesn't really match the input from the question.

Comment: @lewicz ok. let me know if something doesn't work (meaning I misunderstood the question)

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks. Now it's inserting hex instead of ascii:
unsigned char code[] = "x
                           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: I thought you want hex. Btw, depending on the size of the output, the whole thing might fail with an `argument list too long error` when `${string}` becomes too large

Comment: @hek2mgl hex as ascii: \x90\x0a\x0d and so on.

Comment: I tried the above commands with the `ls` binary and get the following output: `unsigned char code[] = "\x48\x83\xec\x08 ... "`. ( but see my previous comment  about the possible _argument list too long_ error)

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410980/include-a-text-file-in-a-c-program-as-a-char

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, I would suggest that you look at this problem more of a "template" than a "replacement." That is, rename your file from `file.c` to `file.c.template`. Then put markup in your template that is what you want to modify. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() { 
unsigned char code[] = \
<% code_hex_string %>
printf("Length:  %d\n", strlen(code));

    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;
    ret();
    return 0;


}
```

Now all your `sed` has to do is replace `<% code_hex_string %>` with the actual hex string, and you're done.

```
sed -e 's/<%\s*code_hex_string\s*%>/'"$j"'/' < file.c.template > file.c
```

Once you have this concept, it translates well to other languages as well, and you can grow your bash script into perl / python / groovy / C# / whatever fairly easily.

Comment: Well i've tried that, the problem is that it's inserting hex code instead of ASCII as hex code:

unsigned char code[] ="1��1۳1�Rho
�hHell��1Ҳ̀1��1�̀"

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this:

```
export j=''
for b in $(objdump -d -M intel /bin/ls | grep "^ " | cut -f2); do j+='\\x'$b; done; echo $j
sed "s/{{PLACEHOLDER}}/${j}/" file.c
```