# Is it possible to load a string from a file during compile time? C++

Tags: c++

Is there a function or a method to load data from a file into a variable during compile time in C++?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: How about define the string in the header file?

Comment: You can `#include` any file you want.

Comment: I would rather load the data from the file, I.E, fstream style, but how would you do that statically?

Comment: You might want to look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410980/include-a-text-file-in-a-c-program-as-a-char).

Comment: If the marked original does not answer your question, edit this question to specify more clearly what you need to do and to distinguish that from the other question.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a **function** or a **method** to load data from a file into a variable during **compile time** in C++?

Only `constexpr` functions can be evaluated at compile time. As far as I'm aware, no file processing function is `constexpr`, hence the answer to your question is "no".

You may consider other options:

- have that file contain a properly formatted and quoted string and put `#include` directive where an initializer for your string should have been (on a separate line, obviously);
- resort to good-old makefile magic to run a script which would convert the text file to a proper C++ source when compiling the project.

Comment: "as far as I'm aware, no file processing function is constexpr" Yes that is correct and that is intentional. A `constexpr` function must not have any source of UB because otherwise you could not guarantee the compilation correctness. So you can't have any kind of constexpr IO operation.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it during configuration time with cmake

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html