# objcopy prepends directory pathname to symbol name

Tags: c++, c, objcopy

I am tying to use `objcopy` to include a binary form of a text file into an executable. (At runtime I need the file as a string). This works fine until the linker needs to find the references from the symbol names. The problem is that `objcopy` prepends the symbol names with the pathname to the file. Since I am using GNU Autotools to ship the package this prepended pathname changes and I don't know what external linker symbol to use in the C/C++ program.

```
nm libtest.a |grep textfile
textfile.o:
00001d21 D _binary__home_git_textfile_end
00001d21 A _binary__home_git_textfile_size
00000000 D _binary__home_git_textfile_start
```

`libtest.a` was produced with (extract from Makefile.am):

```
SUFFIXES = .txt
.txt.$(OBJEXT):
    objcopy --input binary --output elf32-i386 --binary-architecture i386 $< $@
```

How can I tell `objcopy` to only us the stem of the filename as linker symbols? Or is there another way around the problem?

Answer (score 11):

Somewhat ironically you can use `objcopy` to solve the problem via the `--redefine-sym` option that allows renaming of symbols...

> If I use objcopy to create an object file from a PNG in another
>   directory:
>
> ```
> $ objcopy -I binary -O elf64-x86-64 -B i386 --rename-section .data=.rodata,alloc,load,data,contents,readonly ../../resources/test.png test_png.o
> ```
>
> The resulting object has the following symbols:
>
> ```
> $readelf -s test_png.o -W
>
> Symbol table '.symtab' contains 5 entries:
>    Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
>      0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
>      1: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
>      2: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _binary_______resources_test_png_start
>      3: 0000000000003aaa     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _binary_______resources_test_png_end
>      4: 0000000000003aaa     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _binary_______resources_test_png_size
> ```
>
> These can then be renamed:
>
> ```
> $objcopy --redefine-sym _binary_______resources_test_png_start=_binary_test_png_start test_png.o
> $objcopy --redefine-sym _binary_______resources_test_png_size=_binary_test_png_size test_png.o
> $objcopy --redefine-sym _binary_______resources_test_png_end=_binary_test_png_end test_png.o
> ```
>
> Resulting in an object with the symbol names that objcopy would have
>   generated if the PNG had been located in the current directory:
>
> ```
> $readelf -s test_png.o -W
>
> Symbol table '.symtab' contains 5 entries:
>    Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
>      0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
>      1: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
>      2: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _binary_test_png_start
>      3: 0000000000003aaa     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _binary_test_png_end
>      4: 0000000000003aaa     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _binary_test_png_size
> ```

Comment: The mention of `--redefine-sym` is a good one, but it seems insufficient: how is the caller of objcopy supposed to know how to form the "original" symbol name?  I note that if the input file to objcopy is something like `../../foo/bar.txt` the symbol name is something horrible like `_binary________foo_bar_txt_start`.  Having to encode the logic to turn dots, slashes, and perhaps other characters (which?) into underscores seems pretty silly. And bizarrely, objcopy's `--wildcard` option could help us, but it seems to have no effect with `--redefine-sym` (I suppose they intend it for other uses).

Comment: @JohnZwinck: You only need to be able to reconstruct the non-directory portion, then objdump for the names and check which ends in your desired name, and then use that for renaming.

Comment: Looking at the code, all non-alphnumeric characters are converted to `_`. So the following converts the filename `echo -n "$filename" | tr -c '[A-Za-z0-9]' '_'`. Prepend `_binary_` and append `_start` and others.

Answer (score 11):

Generic method of including raw data into ELF is supported by [.incbin](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Incbin.html) assembler directive.

The trick is to create template .S file that could look like this:

```
        .global foo_start
foo_start:
        .incbin "foo.raw"

        .global foo_end
foo_end:
```

This file is preprocessed via cpp so we don't have to hardcode file name there, eg. we can write:

```
        .incbin __raw_file_path__
```

... and then pass it while compiling:

```
gcc -D__raw_file_path__='"data/foo.png"' foo.S -c -o data/foo.o
```

Lastly, as we prepare .S file ourself we can add some extra data and/or information.  If you include raw "text files" and want these to be available as C strings you can add '0' byte just after raw data:

```
        .global foo_start
foo_start:
        .incbin "foo.raw"

        .global foo_end
foo_end:    
        .byte 0

        .global foo_size
foo_size:
        .int foo_end - foo_start
```

If you want full-blown flexibility, you can of course pre-process file manually to alter any part of it, eg.

```
.global @sym@_start
@sym@_start:
       .incbin "@file@"
       .global @sym@_end
@sym@_end:
```

... and then compile it:

```
sed -e "s,@sym@,passwd,g" -e "s,@file@,/etc/passwd," <foo.S.in | gcc -x assembler-with-cpp - -o passwd.o -c
```

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative which I have used is to `cd` to the source directory and then give `objcopy` the basename of the source.  In `bash`, this would be:

```
cd $(dirname $SOURCE)
objcopy ... $(basename $SOURCE) $TARGET
```

This way the symbols generated are always `_binary_file_name_xxx` without the path.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this with cmake, and I ended up using /dev/stdin as input to get consistent symbols name, then redefining the symbols thanks to
   string(MAKE_C_IDENTIFIER ...)
And then use objcopy --redefine-sym on the resulting object file.

The resulting function is then :

```
function(make_binary_object __file)
    get_filename_component(__file_name ${__file} NAME)
    set(__object ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${__file_name}.obj)
    string(MAKE_C_IDENTIFIER ${__file_name} __file_c_identifier)
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${__object}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY}
            --input-format binary
            --output-format elf64-x86-64
            --binary-architecture i386:x86-64
            /dev/stdin
            ${__object} < ${__file}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY}
            --redefine-sym _binary__dev_stdin_start=_binary_${__file_c_identifier}_start
            --redefine-sym _binary__dev_stdin_end=_binary_${__file_c_identifier}_end
            --redefine-sym _binary__dev_stdin_size=_binary_${__file_c_identifier}_size
            ${__object}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        DEPENDS ${__file})
    set_source_files_properties(${__object} PROPERTIES EXTERNAL_OBJECT TRUE)
endfunction()
```

And you can use it like this:

```
make_binary_object(index.html)

add_executable(my_server
    server.c
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/index.html.obj)
```

Answer (score -2):

One simple solution is to transform your text file into what could be used to initialize an array of char. So, you'd get 0x41,0x42,0x43,0x30,0x31,0x32 for "ABC012". You can then #include this sequence of bytes. You can also *escape* all non-ASCII chars instead of converting everything into bytes so that most of the text is still readable in the generated include file.

Comment: Using `stdin` and `extern` avoid to store the source.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: using `-x<language>` and `-` as input for `gcc`/`g++`

Comment: @Alex How's that helpful? Sorry, I'm not following you.

Comment: this way `xxd -i input.txt | sed 's/input_txt/test/' | gcc -c -xc - -o obj.o`