# C++ program to dump a boiler plate C++

Tags: c++

I have a C++ program which dumps out a C++ program. Some of the functions are boiler plate code and certain functions has boiler plate code and code tailored based on a few variables.

A simplified example is presented below:

```
// Snippet: 1
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ofstream fout("output.cc");

    // bp() has just boiler plate code
    fout << "void bp() {" << endl;
    fout << "std::cout << \"Hello World!\" << std::endl" << endl;
    // a few hundred lines of C++ code send to fout
    fout << "}" << endl;

    // mix() has boiler plate + some custom code
    int size = 4096;
    fout << "void mix() {" << endl;
    fout << "char buffer[" << size << "];" << endl;
    // a few hundred lines of C++ code send to fout
    fout << "}" << endl;

    // compile output.cc into *.so and delete output.cc

    return 0;
}
```

The `output.cc` gets compiled and user gets the `*.so` file. The user does not have access to `output.cc`.

I wanted to rewrite this since it is difficult to read the boiler plate code when it is inside `fout` and having escaped quotes makes it a nightmare. Hence I thought of storing the functions in a separate file. For example have `bp()` in `bp.cc`:

```
// file: bp.cc
void bp() {
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl
    // a few hundred lines of C++ code 
}
```

Then the main file can be [written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195343/copy-a-file-in-an-sane-safe-and-efficient-way) as

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream  src("bp.cc");
    std::ofstream  dst("output.cc");

    dst << src.rdbuf();
}
```

In case of `mix()` I would use the [Form-Letter Programming](http://bit.ly/1bJJ21L) by storing the function `mix()` in `mix.cc`.

When the functions `bp()` and `mix()` were dumped using `fout` as in `Snippet:1`, all I had to do was ship the executable since the `Snippet:1` is self-contained. But

- If I split the functions into separate files `bp()` into `bp.cc` and `mix()` into `mix.cc` how do I ship it as a single executable? I need to ship `bp.cc` and `mix.cc` along with the executable. I do not want the user to access `bp.cc` and `mix.cc`.
- Is there a better way to rewrite the `Snippet:1` than what I have suggested to better suit my needs?

Comment: You might need to have something like a resource compiler that _bundles_ in the files with your executable. Another option might be to have another little tool, that generates all the _'horrible'_ escaping syntax for the original code templates given, and outputs a compilable c++ file with certain literals (e.g. `static const char[]`) for the templates.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Post this as an answer?

Comment: Oh, nevermind - it's [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/328137/509868) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/411000/509868)

Comment: @anatolyg Thanks for feeding in the links. I didn't really want to make this an answer, there are just pointers ...

Comment: @anatolyg Hmm, is this a double duplicate then?? I think the [latter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410980/include-a-text-file-in-a-c-program-as-a-char/411000#411000) is the most concise answer to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use raw string literals and just put the code into one of those:

```
#include <iostream>

char const source[] = R"end(
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "hello, world\n";
}
)end";

int main()
{
    std::cout << source;
}
```

Comment: We have not upgraded to C++11 yet. Is there a solution for the older versions? We do have access to Boost.