# CodeBlocks - How to add an icon to a C program?

Tags: c, windows, icons, codeblocks, resource-files

I have a small C console program and I want to add an .ico file to it, so that the executable looks nice.

How can I do this in CodeBlocks with MinGW/gcc?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I could not find relevant help via google that a total beginner (like me for C) could follow, so I will Q&A this topic.

- First of all you need an .ico file. Put it in the folder with your main.c file.
- In CodeBlocks go to `File -> New -> Empty File` and name it `icon.rc`. It has to be visible in the Workspace/Project otherwise CodeBlocks will not be aware of this file. It will show up there in a project folder called `Resources` .
- Put the following line in it: `MAINICON ICON "filename.ico"`. MAINICON is just an identifier, you can choose something different. [More info 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/icon-resource) & [More info 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/about-resource-files).
- Save the files and compile - CodeBlocks will do everything else for you

What will happen now, is `windres.exe` (the [Resource Compiler](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/windres.1.html)) compiling the resource script `icon.rc` and the icon to an object binary file to `obj\Release\icon.res`. And the linker will add it to the executable.

It's so easy yet it took me quite a while to find it out - I hope I can save someone else having the same problem some time.

Comment: By "visible in the workspace", I take it you actually mean "added to the project"?

Comment: Yes. There will be several project folders visible - "Sources" with the .c files and now "Resources" with the icon.rc file. If you created the iron.rc file with a text editor outside of CodeBlocks, you have to add it to the workspace via `Project -> Add Files`.

Comment: My point is that these are project-specific. Any Windows linker will want a .res file, which is the binary generated from the .rc script. This is a Windows standard and not unique to Mingw.

Comment: now how you have to use an image inside an .rc file in your project?