# Adding existing *.bin file to project in gnu arm eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gcc, embedded, newlib

I have 2 separate projects: bootloader and application.

While building bootloader project I've added the following line in post-build steps in Eclipse:
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -S  -O binary  "${ProjName}.elf" "${ProjName}.bin", so *.bin file was created.

Now, in the application project, I'd like to add this *.bin at specified addresses in order to produce one *.hex/*elf file.

Can arm-none-eabi-objcopy be used for this purpose?
Or is there linker command that could combine existing *.bin file from bootloader project and *.o files from application project during linking?

Answer (score 0):

Here seems to be a bunch of suggestions on how you might accomplish what you want:

[Include binary file with GNU ld linker script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327609/include-binary-file-with-gnu-ld-linker-script)